# A confusing situation about mysql query sql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> explain select comment from test_users where comment="3";
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_users | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1997187 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

according to this situation above, should it return the result immediately within no time cost because the field select and where is the same one, but after scanned 1997187 rows??

Comment: the rows are estimated if you are using InnoDB engine..

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` output tells me that for you unknown query.it cannot/will not use indexes.. And it will scan the FULL table file ("type: ALL") and it thinks it need to scan a estimated of 1997187 rows to find the answer.. The `Extra: Using Where` tells me that MysQL also needs to start a algorthm ("wasting" CPU cycles) to filter out the records or skip non matches from the results to get a output matching the `WHERE` more or less like in "pseudo code" `for (records as record) { if(record.column['comment'] != 3; continue;  output[] = record; }`